# Assembly.GetTypes() throws ReflectionTypeLoadException because of a protected abstract method

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to dynamically load assemblies and get the types in them, but I'm running into this exception:

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Method 'HandleAuthenticateAsync' in type 'My.Namespace.Api.Attributes.BasicAuthenticationHandler' from assembly 'My.Namespace.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.'

This type inherits from the abstract class `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`, which has the abstract method:
`protected abstract Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync();`

I'm loading these assemblies from a separate dotnet 7 application - is there a way to load these assemblies in such a way that I can see non public types/fields/methods/etc through reflection? I also have access to the projects themselves, so I could build them with different settings if that's necessary.

My code:

```cs
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"C:\mypublish folder\bin\Debug\net6.0\win-x64";
        AssemblyLoader loader = new AssemblyLoader(path);
        Assembly loadedAssembly = loader.LoadFromAssemblyName(new AssemblyName("My.Namespace.Api"));

        LoadReferencedAssembly(loader, loadedAssembly);
        Type[] types = loadedAssembly.GetTypes();
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, Assembly> loadedAssembliesDict { get; set; } 
        = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                 .DistinctBy(x => x.FullName)
                                 .ToDictionary(x => x.FullName);
    private static Dictionary<string, AssemblyName> loadedAssemblyNamesDict { get; set; } 
        = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                 .Select(x => x.GetName())
                                 .DistinctBy(x => x.FullName)
                                 .ToDictionary(x => x.FullName);

    private static void LoadReferencedAssembly(AssemblyLoader loader, Assembly assembly)
    {
        if (!loadedAssembliesDict.ContainsKey(assembly.FullName))
            loadedAssembliesDict.Add(assembly.FullName, assembly);

        AssemblyName currentName = assembly.GetName();
        if (!loadedAssemblyNamesDict.ContainsKey(currentName.FullName))
            loadedAssemblyNamesDict.Add(currentName.FullName, currentName);

        foreach (AssemblyName name in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
        {
            if (!loadedAssemblyNamesDict.ContainsKey(name.FullName))
            {
                LoadReferencedAssembly(loader, loader.LoadFromAssemblyName(name));
            }
        }
    }
}


public class AssemblyLoader : AssemblyLoadContext
{
    private string folderPath;

    public AssemblyLoader(string folderPath)
    {
        this.folderPath = folderPath;
    }

    protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        var deps = DependencyContext.Default;

        var res = deps.CompileLibraries.Where(d => d.Name.Contains(assemblyName.Name)).ToList();
        if (res.Count > 0)
        {
            return Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(res.First().Name));
        }
        else
        {
            var apiApplicationFileInfo = new FileInfo($"{folderPath}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}{assemblyName.Name}.dll");
            if (File.Exists(apiApplicationFileInfo.FullName))
            {
                var asl = new AssemblyLoader(apiApplicationFileInfo.DirectoryName);
                return asl.LoadFromAssemblyPath(apiApplicationFileInfo.FullName);
            }
        }

        return Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code where you call `Assembly.GetTypes()`.

Comment: @Dai - code added

Comment: (It's off-topic, but your dictionary members should be `private static readonly` fields, not mutable properties; if you ever add multi-threading or concurrency then change them to `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>`)

Comment: The `.DistinctBy(x => x.FullName)` step should be unnecessary.

Comment: I think I did an exception because of duplicate keys without the ```.DistinctBy(x => x.FullName)``` (which, of course, I now can't replicate). And yeah, this is super messy, I'm just trying to get it working before making it not ugly.